# Python matplotlib Построение гиперболы

Tags: python, график, matplotlib

Добрый день! Хочу при помощи matplotlib построить, например, гиперболу. Есть следующий код:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pylab, math
xmin = -200
xmax = 200
dx = 0.1

xlist = [float(x) for x in range(xmin,xmax)]
ylist = [float(1/x) for x in range(xmin,xmax)]


ax = plt.gca()
ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position(('data',0))
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')
ax.spines['left'].set_position(('data',0))
plt.grid(True)
plt.title('График функции ')
pylab.plot(xlist,ylist)
pylab.savefig('123.png')
```

Пример работы на картинке
Как видно, между двумя ветвями функции есть отрезок. Я знаю, что это связанно с тем, что есть значение крайних точек ветвей, а плот их соединяет. Но это мне не нужно, мне нужно получить нормальный график. Если бы этот график был всегда гиперболой, было бы нормально. Но этим графиком может быть любой график с разрывом. Как избежать этого отрезка? Видел способы, но там использовались дополнительные пакеты(numpy), я не хочу тянуть их в этот код
[[image: введите сюда описание изображения]]

Comment: Вроде matplotlib без numpy не заведется? http://matplotlib.org/users/installing.html#build-requirements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для начала повторюсь, что `matplotlib` уже внутри себя использует `numpy`, так что избежать его не выйдет. Тем не менее, вот первая версия без `numpy` в основном коде:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import decimal


# Это замена np.arange
def arange(start, stop, step):
    while start < stop:
        yield start
        start += decimal.Decimal(step)


hyperbola = lambda x: 1 / x


def asymptote_checker(argument, function):
    try:
        function(argument)
        return True
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return False

xmin = -20
xmax = 20
dx = 0.1

xlist = [round(x, 4) for x in arange(xmin, xmax, dx)]

ylist = [hyperbola(x) if asymptote_checker(x, hyperbola) else float('nan') for x in xlist]

plt.plot(xlist, ylist)
plt.show()
```

С numpy выйдет покороче:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import decimal
import numpy as np

xmin = -20
xmax = 20
dx = 0.1

xlist = np.around(np.arange(xmin, xmax, dx), decimals=4)

ylist = 1 / xlist

plt.plot(xlist, ylist)
plt.show()
```

Пара общих важных моментов для обеих версий: числа в `xlist` вместо нуля могут внезапно превратиться в мусор типа `7.0485345e-13` или типа того, что выльется в огромное значение по оси `Oy`. Второй момент - `matplotlib` игнорирует (и не соединяет точки) числа типа +inf, -inf, NaN - их можно пометить руками, доверить это `numpy` или использовать [numpy masked array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.html).